# How can I modify the instance name for an ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, ec2-api-tools

I would like to modify the "name" attribute of an amazon instance.  See attached screenshot.  I need to do it programmatically, but can't find anywhere in the EC2 API how to set that.

If it matters, I'm launching these via a spot request through their API.  I would like to set the field that I tagged, "set this name" in the image below.

[image: screen shot of field to set]

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This might help...

```
AmazonEC2 ec2;    
AWSCredentials credentials;
String accKey = "your access key";
String secKey = "your secret key";    

credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accKey, secKey);
ec2 = new AmazonEC2Client(credentials);

String instanceId = "Your Instance ID";
List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<Tag>();

Tag t = new Tag();
t.setKey("Name");
t.setValue("my server!");
tags.add(t);

Tag t = new Tag();
t.setKey("owner");
t.setValue("me");
tags.add(t);

CreateTagsRequest ctr = new CreateTagsRequest();
ctr.setTags(tags);
ctr.withResources(instanceId);
ec2.createTags(ctr);
```

kind of quick and dirty, but you get the idea.

Comment: FYI you need "Name" (uppercase), instead of "name" to set that name.

Comment: You can also use the [aws command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html) like so: `aws ec2 create-tags --resources i-??????? --tag Key=Name,Value="MY INSTANCE NAME"`

Answer (score 19):

You can do it through AWS console UI:

[image: ec2]

Comment: This UI feature is so annoyingly not-obvious if you don't expect it.  Instances come nameless by default, so good luck thinking "Oh, I should mouse over this blank space to add it there"

Comment: Number of developers at AWS: thousands.
Number of UX specialists at AWS: 0

Comment: I had even gotten to the point of seeing that icon, but didn't realize it was supposed to indicate "edit"...

Comment: Hilarious comments and same here. Truly hate to say it but for once I find a MS product much more user friendly. Azure is a MUCH more intuitive, friendly and usable UI.

Answer (score 14):

In 2021 this can be done from the AWS console, by going to **EC2** > **Instances**, clicking the instance ID, then in the bottom panel clicking on the **Tags** tab, and clicking **Manage tags**. From there, you can simply change the value of the **Name** tag then click **Save** to apply.

Answer (score 4):

Further digging into the API and I found what I was looking for.

These are known as tags.  You can assign them to nearly any aws entity (some things are excepted, e.g., you can't add a tag to an elastic ip).

You can set keyname/keyvalue pairs through the API.  Documentation is here: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-CreateTags.html

Then you can filter results by these tags, or choose to display them in the web interface.